# Trouble downloading images into array from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Here is the code I'm having trouble with.

Shared:

```
// Firebase services
var database: FIRDatabase!
var storage: FIRStorage!
...
// Initialize Database, Auth, Storage
database = FIRDatabase.database()
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
...
// Initialize an array for your pictures
var picArray: [UIImage]()
```

Upload:

```
let fileData = NSData() // get data...
let storageRef = storage.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
storageRef.putData(fileData).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
// When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
// Write the download URL to the Realtime Database
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
dbRef.setValue(downloadURL)
```

}

Download:

```
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles")
dbRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
// Get download URL from snapshot
let downloadURL = snapshot.value() as! String
// Create a storage reference from the URL
let storageRef = storage.referenceFromURL(downloadURL)
// Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
// Create a UIImage, add it to the array
let pic = UIImage(data: data)
picArray.append(pic)
 })
})
```

I've been trying to use the above code posted originally by @Mike-McDonald a few months ago, to pull and append an array of images from my Firebase DB.  I am successfully able to upload images using the above, but for the life of me, I cannot get the images to download, nor append to an images array.

I'm not getting any errors - it's just that simply the "download" code does not appear to be running (I've tried to verify this in the console as well).  A couple of lines are different for Swift 3, but the only one that I'm unsure about is:

```
let storageRef = storage.referenceFromURL(downloadURL)
```

is now

```
let storageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL)
```

Any suggestions on this, or on how to create/append an array of images using the childadded observer with Firebase would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me except that you have to update to `data(withMaxSize:completion)`, `observe(_:with:)` and use `reference(forURL:)` like you already mentioned. So you need the code to update to this:

```
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles")
dbRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snaphot) in
  // Get download URL from snapshot
  let downloadURL = snapshot.value() as! String
  // Create a storage reference from the URL
  let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL)
  // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
  storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
    let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
    picArray.append(pic)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made these changes already. Still having problem getting download code to fully execute.

Comment: I see, download definitely works with this piece of code. So you use the code as you mentioned as basic for your own usage. Maybe you should add more parts of your own code and also explain more in detail what you try to achieve. It seems that the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this in my case. I wasn't uploading the image as data. And so the download as data was never happening. It doesn't trigger an error, it just doesn't execute. Here is the change I made:

```
let fileData = NSData()
```

changed to:

```
let fileData = (UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagefile.image!)! as NSData?)!
```

It's working perfectly now!